# Saving table/column updates c# entity

Tags: c#, entity

I am trying to find a neater way to save table/column updates. I have an object representing the current order table entry and an object with all updated values. I want to compare each variable with matching names in each object and save the update to the database if different.
The current way I am doing this (which I know is badly written) is as follows:

```
if (currentOrder.Comment != editedOrder.Comment)
{
    createOrderUpdateRecord("Comment", currentOrder.Comment.ToString(), editedOrder.Comment.ToString(), OrderID);
    currentOrder.Comment = editedOrder.Comment ;
    anyChangesMade = true;
}
if (currentOrder.CustomerName != editedOrder.CustomerName )
{
    createOrderUpdateRecord("CustomerName ", currentOrder.CustomerName .ToString(), editedOrder.CustomerName .ToString(), OrderID);
    currentOrder.CustomerName = editedOrder.CustomerName ;
    anyChangesMade = true;
}
```

and then in the createOrderUpdateRecord method, I save the information to an edits table.

Comment: In case anyones interested I ended up using the tracker enabled db context library alongside entity framework to track changes to table fields, which did the job perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyones interested I ended up using the tracker enabled db context library alongside entity framework to track changes to table fields, which did the job perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the normal .NET Winforms DataGridView when you refer to table/column-updates:

There is an event called "CellValueChanged". Also there is "CellEndEdit". If you subscribe to either of those, you could set a "changed"-variable to true to track if you must update the value in the database.